# Precommit check-yaml error : "expected a single document in the stream"

Tags: yaml, pre-commit.com

I use precommit with this .pre-commit-config.yaml file (extract) :

```
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    sha: v0.9.2
    hooks:
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: check-yaml
```

and I am stuck with this error :

```
Check Yaml...................Failed
hookid: check-yaml

expected a single document in the stream
  in "modules.yml", line 1, column 1
but found another document
  in "modules.yml", line 4, column 1
```

The beginning of my yaml file is :

```
repo: ssh://git.tranquilit.local/odoo-11-oca-tis/OCB.git
root: 8.0
branch: 8.0-tis
---
repo: ssh://git.tranquilit.local/odoo-71-tis/tis-addons.git
origin: tis
branch: 8.0
modules:
    #- attachment_rename
    #- partner_firstname
    - tis_account_analytic_recurrent_invoicing
```

I tried with and without a leading line --- but it changes only the line nb of the error.

I didn't found any help anywhere on the web, so if anybody can help me, I would be greatefull for that !

Thanks by advance, Herve

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is now solved in pre-commit version 1.1.0 : https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/635
Thanks for your help.

You can enable this new option by setting `args: [--allow-multiple-documents]`, for example:

```
    hooks:
    -   id: check-yaml
        args: [--allow-multiple-documents]
```

Comment: FYI I had the same issue with v2.5.0 and this setting helped.

Answer (score 3):

`---` starts a new YAML document in your file. So you have two YAML documents in your file, and this is what the error complains about. Based on the documentation of pre-commit, I assume you want to make it a sequence instead:

```
- repo: ssh://git.tranquilit.local/odoo-11-oca-tis/OCB.git
  root: 8.0
  branch: 8.0-tis
- repo: ssh://git.tranquilit.local/odoo-71-tis/tis-addons.git
  origin: tis
  branch: 8.0
  modules:
    #- attachment_rename
    #- partner_firstname
    - tis_account_analytic_recurrent_invoicing
```

Comment: Your solution is correct, thanks,  
but in fact I do need to use a multi-document yaml file,  
so your solution is not appropriate in my context,  
does anybody has a trick to precommit a multi-document yaml file ?

Comment: It may be better to direct a feature request to pre-commit than to ask for a workaround here. However, I wonder why you need a multi-document yaml file. If you process it somewhere else, couldn't you alter that process to take a sequence instead?

Comment: Sorry, I searched but I didnt find where to put a feature request about pre-commit, can you give the address of the appropriate forum to post it ? Thanks in advance, Herve

Comment: There is an issue tracker [at GitHub](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues), which I assume is the right place. But I am not a maintainer nor a user of pre-commit.